# I can't stress enough how this position/job is appropriate for me

Tags: word-choice, word-request, formal-language, informal-language

I wrote the following sentence but am not sure enough if it is appropriate to use it in a job interview and if the word "appropriate" is good choice for the sentence to show your willingness and eagerness.

> I can't stress enough how this position/job is appropriate for me

1. Is 'I can't stress enough" too informal for a job interview or for a job application cover?
2. Which words I can use instead of " appropriate" if it sounds as if it is not good choice. For example : would *suitable* or *fit* better choices?

Answer (score 1):

“I can’t stress enough” may sound a little pushy, or perhaps even desperate.

I prefer your idea of using the word “fit” in place of “appropriate”.

So I think something like this would work well:

> I really do feel I’d be a good fit for this position.

And mostly importantly, you’d then explain why.

Comment: Thank you. It sounds great!